# option to select which tray to print from

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

A few years ago we had a printer where you had to select which tray you wanted to document to print from via one of the options in Word. Now we have a new printer it still tries to print page 1 from tray 1 and the rest from tray 2 when I want it all to print from tray 1.

How do I stop this from happening as I cannot remember where the setting is inside the documents.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the printer options. What make is the printer?

Comment: its not printer options it an optin in the document. i can set it to print all from tray one on printer but it still splits it between 2 trays